# Export CSV using jqxgrid in Safari browser and iOS is not working

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, safari, jqxgrid

In my web application i have an option to export "jqxgrid" data to ".CSV" format.

It is working as expected in Chrome & Firefox browsers.  But, if, I tried the export option in 'Safari' browser it is opening it is in another tab, instead of download it as a separate file.

Is it possible to download it as a separate file?

### **Sample Code:**

```
 $("#gridExport").click(function () {
        exportData = [];
        var exportType = GetExportFormat(); //csv (or) xls
        exportInfo = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', exportType);
        exportInfo = replaceAll(exportInfo, '&lt;br/&gt;', ' ');
        try {
            var prm = {};
            prm.exportInfo = exportInfo;
            saveMyFile("$('SubmitForm')", "Test" + "." + exportType, exportInfo, "text/" + exportType + ";charset=utf-8");
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log('Export Error: ' + e);
        }
    });


function saveMyFile(ref, fname, text, mime) {
    try {
        var blob = new Blob([text], { type: mime });
        saveAs(blob, fname);
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('saveMyFile: ' + e.message);
    }
}



   function GetExportFormat() {    
        var strPlatform = navigator.platform;
        if (strPlatform.toLowerCase().indexOf('ipad') > -1 || 
               strPlatform.toLowerCase().indexOf('iphone') > -1 ||                   
               strPlatform.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') > -1)
            return "csv";
        else
            return "xls";
    }
```